# OrmLite get value from listView with Adapter

Tags: java, android, ormlite

When I want to get a name of list which I pressed, I get **"com.example.oleksandr.dream.DB.DreamDetails@528f8a90"**. How can I get a String value from my list? The problem is in **"the onItemClick"** methode.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private DBHelper mDbHelper = null;
private DreamDetails dreamDetails;
private ListView mListView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Dao<DreamDetails, Integer> dreamDetailsDao;
private List<DreamDetails> dreamList;
private int selectedRecordPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAllDreams);
    try {
        //Getting all Data from DB
        dreamDetailsDao = getHelper().getDreamDetailsesDao();
        dreamList = dreamDetailsDao.queryForAll();

        // Set the header of the ListView
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, mListView, false);
        mListView.addHeaderView(view);

        // my own adapter!
        mListView.setAdapter(new AdapterArrayDream(this,R.layout.list_view,dreamList,dreamDetailsDao));
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initToolbar();
    initNavigationView();
    FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewDream.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if(i > 0)
    {
        selectedRecordPosition = i - 1;
       // final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewDream.class);
        Log.i("TAAAAAAG", "onClick " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(selectedRecordPosition));
    //    intent.putExtra("D", String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(selectedRecordPosition)));
      //  startActivity(intent);
    }
}
private void initNavigationView() {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawlerLayout);
}
private void initToolbar() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
  //  mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
}

// This is how, DatabaseHelper can be initialized for future use



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_dreams, menu);
    return true;
}

private DBHelper getHelper() {
    if (mDbHelper == null) {
        mDbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DBHelper.class);
    }
    return mDbHelper;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a query which looks up an account by name and password you would do the following:

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> qb = accountDao.queryBuilder();
     Where where = qb.where();
     // the name field must be equal to "foo"
     where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo");
     // and
     where.and();
     // the password field must be equal to "_secret"
     where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret");
     PreparedQuery<Account, String> preparedQuery = qb.prepareQuery();
```